# Need help understanding magento order state workflow

Tags: order-status

1)

When a user first places an order the state will be 'new' which I understand makes the order non visible.

Given this state we can assign statuses like 'new' and 'pending' which I believe makes the order visible.

2)

If the order's payment method is set to 'auth & capture' 
or if either 'invoice' or 'ship' is completed for an order but not both then the state will be 'processing`.

For such orders, statuses can be 'shipped' or 'invoiced'.

3.

If both are completed then the state will be `completed` as will the status.

So my doubt is how magento understand particular state is `new` or `processing` or `completed` ?

is there any event-observer functionality for this?

I mean if user clicks place order button any observer will trigger?

**Is there any definition for each state?**

Comment: What is your magento version?  In early versions there was a XML configuration, not the states are in the DB.

Comment: magento 1.9 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in the model sales/order (so `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`).
It has a `_beforeSave()` method which calls a method called `_checkState()`.
Inside that `_checkState()` method (only part of it):

```
if (!$this->isCanceled()
    && !$this->canUnhold()
    && !$this->canInvoice()
    && !$this->canShip()) {
    if (0 == $this->getBaseGrandTotal() || $this->canCreditmemo()) {
        if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_COMPLETE) {
            $this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Order can be closed just in case when we have refunded amount.
     * In case of "0" grand total order checking ForcedCanCreditmemo flag
     */
    elseif (floatval($this->getTotalRefunded()) || (!$this->getTotalRefunded()
        && $this->hasForcedCanCreditmemo())
    ) {
        if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_CLOSED) {
            $this->_setState(self::STATE_CLOSED, true, '', $userNotification);
        }
    }
}

if ($this->getState() == self::STATE_NEW && $this->getIsInProcess()) {
    $this->setState(self::STATE_PROCESSING, true, '', $userNotification);
}
```

So depending on your state of the order, e.g. see the last two lines if the state was new and the order has getIsInProcess() (which basically checks for invoices / shipmments), then the state will be changed to processing.